# spacemacs custom autocomplete java

Tags: java, spacemacs, eclim

I have set up and am using Spacemacs with Eclim for enterprise Java development, but am looking for a way to set up a custom autocomplete rule so that (like in many IDEs), typing `sout` and hitting tab will autocomplete & expand to `System.out.println()`.

Where would I define a custom autocomplete rule? Is there a layer that already enables such shorthand autocompletion?

Comment: Why not just use a free IDE that already does this? -> I use IntelliJ IDEA Community and am not disappointed by it, *yet*.

Comment: There is a chance that I will end up moving over to use Eclipse or IntelliJ but for the time being, I like the idea of sticking with a programmable editor, have had success with Spacemacs and I am trying to see if I can stick with it and make it work for my use case.

Comment: Maybe you want to ask this question on the specific [emacs stackexchange site](https://emacs.stackexchange.com), seems to be more suited, but before posting read their [help site](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/help)